# Type mismatch: cannot convert from double [] to int []

Tags: java, arrays, class, for-loop, methods

I am trying to have the method return the new array that was made by the for loop.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class stocks {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    double stockV [] = {55.6, 63.2, 68.1, 70.1, 72.4, 73.9, 71.5, 68.3, 67.1, 66.2}; 
    double isOverprices [] = overpriced(stockV);

}
    public int [] overpriced(double[] rsiValues)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rsiValues.length; i++)
        {
            if (rsiValues[i] > 70)
            {
                rsiValues[i] = 1;
            }
            else if (rsiValues[i] <= 70)
            {
                rsiValues[i] = 0;
            }
            return rsiValues;
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
public double[] overpriced(double[] rsiValues)
```

You are obviously returning what you pass into the method, so why do you think its kind will change?

Also, you want to return the values after the `for` loop has ended.

```
for (int i = 0; i < rsiValues.length; i++)
{
    if (rsiValues[i] > 70)
    {
        rsiValues[i] = 1;
    }
    else if (rsiValues[i] <= 70)
    {
        rsiValues[i] = 0;
    }

}
return rsiValues;
```

Comment: my goal here is to turn anything above a seventy to a 1 and anything seventy or less into 0. I am trying to create a new array that will hold the new values as well as to display the array

Comment: Create a new array of hints to hold the values. Perhaps booleans would be better.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add 'static' to the overpriced method signature.
2. The overpriced method should return an array of ints but you're returning an array of doubles.
3. Put your return statement outside of the for loop.
4. In the main method, change isOverprices to an int array

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double stockV [] = {55.6, 63.2, 68.1, 70.1, 72.4, 73.9, 71.5, 68.3, 67.1, 66.2}; 
    int isOverprices [] = overpriced(stockV);
    for(int i: isOverprices) {
      System.out.println(i);
    }
  }
  public static int [] overpriced(double[] rsiValues){
    int result [] = new int[rsiValues.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < rsiValues.length; i++)
    {
      if (rsiValues[i] > 70)
      {
          result[i] = 1;
      }
      else if (rsiValues[i] <= 70)
      {
          result[i] = 0;
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
```